# How can I get Leaflet to ignore NULL or empty objects

Tags: r, leaflet

In the actual problem this variable is created by a script filtering the coordinates specified by the user, so sometimes variables return NULL. After specifying the coordinates I want to run the rest of the script without editing any part of it.

For simplicity I have used the breweries dataset to represent this.

```
##load required package    

    library(mapview)
    library(leaflet)

##create variable with points

    breweries_A <- breweries

##create variable with no points    

    breweries_B <- NULL

##create a leaflet plot

    breweries_plot <- leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = breweries_A) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = breweries_B)
```

The result is an error because breweries B has no data.

Therefore it would be really helpful if there was a way to make leaflet ignore NULL objects, or dataframes with no rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the data conditionally to the map:

```
breweries_plot <- leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') 

if (!is.null(breweries_A))
  breweries_plot <- breweries_plot %>% addCircleMarkers(data = breweries_A)
if (!is.null(breweries_B))
  breweries_plot <- breweries_plot %>% addCircleMarkers(data = breweries_B)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks along the right lines but I can't get it to work. I get the error "Error: unexpected 'if' in:
"if(!is.null(breweries_A)
if" "

Comment: Yeah, I was missing some `)`, fixed now.